# Is FDI the principal route for funds directed offshore to return to a country?

Tags: investment

Is foreign direct investment the principal route for funds directed offshore to return to a country?

For example, the UK has perpetual trade deficit. But the sterling sent overseas must make its way back into the UK economy at some point?

Comment: That is a big one. But the trade deficit in itself does not mean anything. Most transactions occur in the US dollars anyway. I hope that helps!

Comment: was that helpful? Do you need more clarifications? Else can you please accept the answer?